# How to generate a list from permutations of other lists in Mathematica

Tags: list, wolfram-mathematica, permutation

I am stuckwith a fairly simple problem: I need to construct a list with all permutations of values from two different lists in Mathematica.
Let say, `a={1,2}` and `b={4,5}` I would need the result

```
c={{1,4},{1,5},{2,4},{2,5}}
```

Could anybody please give me an idea how to achieve this?
Thanks a lot,

Philipp

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. We can help you with this. What have you attempted so far to solve this? Have you checked the Mathematica documentation, you should be able to find an answer to this, maybe start here. http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/DiscreteMathematics.html

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way

```
In[2]:= Tuples[{{1, 2}, {4, 5}}]

Out[2]= {{1, 4}, {1, 5}, {2, 4}, {2, 5}}
```

Answer (score 3):

The built-in [`Tuples`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Tuples.html) function does precisely what you want:

```
In[1]:= a = {1, 2}; b = {4, 5};

In[2]:= c = Tuples[{a, b}]
Out[2]= {{1, 4}, {1, 5}, {2, 4}, {2, 5}}
```

You can also accomplish this using `Flatten` and the more general [`Outer`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Outer.html):

```
In[3]:= Flatten[Outer[List, a, b], 1]
Out[3]= {{1, 4}, {1, 5}, {2, 4}, {2, 5}}
```

I mention this last fact because a lot of the time when I find myself using `Tuples`, I'm doing so as an intermediate step before immediately `Apply`ing a function to each of the generated sublists, and using `Outer` can save me a step.

Comment: `Distribute[{a,b},List]` is another alternative that might be useful. Unlike `Outer` the result is not nested, obviating the need for `Flatten`.